# What determines input dimension of dense layer at end of a CNN

Tags: python, keras

I'm following [CNN tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/architecture-of-convolutional-neural-networks-simplified-demystified/) at analytics vidhya.

I'm having difficulty visualizing the connection between the flattened layer and the dense layer with 2 nodes and an input dimension of 50.  This is a binary classification problem, so I understand the 2 nodes.  However, what determines the input dimensions?  We can also omit this parameter, in which case there will just be fewer weights to train for this dense layer?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import sklearn
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
import cv2
from skimage import io
%matplotlib inline

#Defining the File Path

cat=os.listdir("/mnt/hdd/datasets/dogs_cats/train/cat")
dog=os.listdir("/mnt/hdd/datasets/dogs_cats/train/dog")
filepath="/mnt/hdd/datasets/dogs_cats/train/cat/"
filepath2="/mnt/hdd/datasets/dogs_cats/train/dog/"

#Loading the Images

images=[]
label = []
for i in cat:
    image = scipy.misc.imread(filepath+i)
    images.append(image)
    label.append(0) #for cat images

for i in dog:
    image = scipy.misc.imread(filepath2+i)
    images.append(image)
    label.append(1) #for dog images

#resizing all the images

for i in range(0,23000):
    images[i]=cv2.resize(images[i],(300,300))

#converting images to arrays

images=np.array(images)
label=np.array(label)

# Defining the hyperparameters

filters=10
filtersize=(5,5)

epochs =5
batchsize=128

input_shape=(300,300,3)

#Converting the target variable to the required size

from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
label = to_categorical(label)

#Defining the model

model = Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))

model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(filters, filtersize, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format="channels_last", activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_dim=50,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(images, label, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batchsize,validation_split=0.3)

model.summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, what determines the input dimensions? We can also omit this
>   parameter, in which case there will just be fewer weights to train for
>   this dense layer?

It is determined by the output shape of the previous layer. As seen from the `model.summary()`, the output shape from Flatten layer is (None, 219040), so the input dimensions to the Dense layer is 219040. So, in this case there are more weights to train(>50).

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 296, 296, 10)      760
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 148, 148, 10)      0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 219040)            0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 438082
=================================================================
Total params: 438,842
Trainable params: 438,842
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As can be seen from the code snippet below, the weights for the dense layer are created based on the `input_shape` parameter(which is the `output_shape` of the previous layer). The `input_dim` passed by the user when constructing the `Dense` layer is ignored.

```
input_dim = input_shape[-1]
self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units),
```

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/3bda5520b787f84f687bb116c460f3aedada039b/keras/layers/core.py#L891

Comment: I'm not following your answer.  If I understand correctly, you're saying that the input_dim=50 argument has no purpose since the actual number of weights is 219040?

Comment: Yes, it is ignored.